# Comparing melting points of substituted benzaldehydes

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, melting-point

> The correct decreasing order of melting point for the given organic compounds is:
> [image: substituted benzaldehydes]

**3** has maximum melting point because of intermolecular hydrogen bonding.

I am unable to predict rest of the order correctly.
**4** should have higher melting point as it shows greater intermolecular hydrogen bonding than the rest, but this contradicts the experimental melting point (mp) data [1]:

$$
\begin{array}{llr}
\hline
\text{#} & \text{Compound} &\text{mp}/\pu{°C} \\
\hline
\textbf{1} & \textit{o}\text{-hydroxybenzaldehyde} & −7(2) \\
\textbf{2} & \textit{o}\text{-methoxybenzaldehyde} & 37.5(0.5) \\
\textbf{3} & \textit{p}\text{-hydroxybenzaldehyde} & 116.0(0.2) \\
\textbf{4} & \textit{p}\text{-methoxybenzaldehyde} & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

#### Reference

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data*, 97th ed.; Taylor & Francis Group (CRC Press): Boca Raton, FL, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.

Comment: melting point depends on how well the molecule packs in a lattice, not neccessarily on strength of H-bond